# How would one calculate the Lunar liftoff thrust required for a spacecraft?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, lunar-orbit, lunar-module

I used the thrust to weight ratio of 2.12 to determine the thrust my spacecraft needs for a lunar liftoff, [Apollo Lunar Ascent Stage Thrust to Weight Ratio](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=29195.0).
Is this a proper way of determining and sizing my spacecraft based on the Thrust needed using the thrust to weight ratio of the Lunar Ascent Module?

Comment: Lunar surfact gravity is 0.17 g. that means that a craft with a thrust to weight ratio of more than 0.17 can lift off. Is that your question?

Comment: If my spacecraft weight for example is 45,000 kg. How much thrust does my engines need to produce? I know you mentioned the gravity. However does my spacecraft also need to satisfy the T/W=2.12, similar to Lunar Ascent Moduls T/W ratio of lunar module.

Comment: When you say T/W, by "W", do you mean the weight on earth, or the weight on the moon?`

Comment: Yes, mass*lunar gravity(1.62 m/s^2 )

Answer (score 3):

You don't need exactly 2.12:1 thrust-to-weight; if you have less, you'll need a little more ∆v to reach orbit, because you'll lose more altitude to gravity on your slower ascent, and if you have more, you'll need a little less ∆v. Obviously you need something more than 1:1 or you won't move until you've burned off enough fuel to drop your weight below your thrust.

The exact performance you need is dependent on a large number of engineering factors, but around 2:1 initial thrust to weight is good rule of thumb for lunar liftoff.

(Taking off from Earth you can get away with something like 1.2-1.4:1 initial T/W instead, which is comparable in initial acceleration.)

For a 45 ton spacecraft, to produce 3.4m/s^2 of acceleration (about 2.1:1 TWR), [Wolfram Alpha tells me you need 153kN of thrust](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(45000kg%20*%203.4%20m%2Fs%5E2)%20in%20newtons).

You can check this against the Apollo Lunar Module ascent stage, which was about 4.7 tons (10.4% of the weight of your spacecraft) and had an engine producing 16kN (10.5% of the thrust of my answer).

Comment: Is there a different approach to take or an equation to determine the thrust required, if I had the Delta-V for Lunar liftoff and mass of my spacecraft?

Comment: Without the thrust and trajectory information, you don't know the ∆v to reach lunar orbit. You'll need to iteratively simulate launch to determine whether you have an appropriate combination of thrust and specific impulse; there's no simple equation for it. What are you actually trying to accomplish?